# Inequality with sum of Binomial coefficients: $\sum\limits^n_{k=1}k \sqrt{\binom nk}\leq\sqrt{2^{n-1}n^3}$

Tags: inequality, induction, binomial-coefficients

Prove that for every positive integer $n \ge 2$
$$\sum^n_{k=1}k \sqrt{\binom nk}\leq\sqrt{2^{n-1}n^3}$$
I tried it by induction but I didn't know how to end it.

Comment: Is Cauchy-Schwarz familiar?

Comment: does that suggest the estimate could be tightened slightly?

Comment: I don't think it can be tightened much (if we use CS the best prefactor we can get in the high $n$ limit is $\sqrt{2/3}$). However one might be able to use residue methods to get a tighter bound. This is significantly more effort though.

Comment: yes, that was all i was thinking of

Comment: Just for fun, here is a one way one can try to find a better bound (if wanted). Let $f(z) = \frac{\sin \pi z}{\pi z(1-z)(1-z/2)\ldots (1-z/n)}$ then $\sum_{k=1}^nk\sqrt{n\choose k}= \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_C \sqrt{f(z)}\frac{\pi z}{\tan(\pi z)}dz$ by the residue theorem where $C$ is a simple contour that wraps once around $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, but not around any other integers. Now one can pick a contour (rectangle seems simplest), and try to estimate the integral.

Comment: @Winther Using CS one can get better that $\sqrt{2/3}$ easily - below I get $\sqrt{1/2}$ and perhaps one can do even better with more care in choosing sequences.

Comment: @Macavity Nicely done (though your inequality only applies for $n>7$). My comment was for the 'obvious' CS application with sequences $k$ and $\sqrt{{n\choose k}}$ for all $n\geq 2$, sure if one picks other sequences one might do better (with larger starting $n$). Though I would be very suprised if one could do significantly better (asymtotically) with CS.

Comment: Experimentally it seems the best asymptotic bound seems to be something along the lines $\frac{0.9}{n^{1/4}}\times \sqrt{2^{n-1}n^3}$

Comment: @Winther Thanks for pointing it worked only for $n> 7$, it should have worked for all $n$ by CS - found and corrected a sign error, now its true for all $n \ge 1$, with equality when $n=1$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments we can get bounds using CS inequality.  Here is a tighter bound using CS and appropriately chosen sequences.  First note that:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k = (1+x)^n \implies \sum_{k=0}^nk \binom{n}{k}x^k = x\frac{d}{dx}(1+x)^n = n x(1+x)^{n-1}$$

$$\implies  \sum_{k=1}^nk \binom{n}{k} = n 2^{n-1} $$

Now by CS inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^nk \right) \cdot \left(\sum_{k=1}^nk \binom{n}{k}\right) \ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{\binom{n}k} \right)^2$$
$$\implies \frac{n(n+1)}2\cdot n 2^{n-1} \ge \left(\sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{\binom{n}k} \right)^2 \implies \sum_{k=1}^n k \sqrt{\binom{n}k} \le n 2^{n/2-1} \sqrt{n+1}$$

P.S. That this bound is tighter than your RHS is easily shown:
$$n 2^{n/2-1} \sqrt{n+1} \le \sqrt{2^{n-1}n^3} \iff n+1 \le 2n \iff n \ge 1$$